# JSF error in Tomcat8 but working in Tomcat7

Tags: linux, jsf, tomcat8

I have a JSF webapp perfectly working in Linux Tomcat7 and Windows (Tomcat7 and Tomcat8.0.24). But in Linux Tomcat8.0.32 it fails with errors :

```
javax.faces.FacesException: /app/login/IndexLogin.jsp (line: 8, column: 0) Absolute Uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core can not resolve 
org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:431)
org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:255)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:138)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:95)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:106)
org.apache.shale.application.faces.ShaleApplicationFilter.doFilter(ShaleApplicationFilter.java:267)
org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147)
```

I've read about JSTL 1.1 and 1.2 and, although I'm not sure how to check which one I'm using, what's driving me nuts is, **why in Windows it works and, in Linux with same jar libraries, it does not?**????

Comment: No way buddy ! I did not explain right myself. I have just 2 hosts, the Windoze one, it all works fine, no matter if Tomcat7 or Tomcat8. But in the Linux host, it works in Tomcat7 and it fails in Tomcat8. NO DNS related at all

Comment: even clearer `>_ curl -s -k -I http://java.sun.com|head -1
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: a nightmare ...hours spent trying to work this out :( :( :(